# Kafka Streams client library compatibility with kafka broker version

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am using kafka client & streams library version 2.7.0 for building my application. However the kafka brokers(2 different clusters) are at older version ( 2.4.1 & 2.6.0).

As i understand we can use the latest clients & Streams library and it should run fine with older version of kafka brokers. Am i correct ? Is there any compatibility matrix between client & streams library with kafka brokers ?

I tried running in my application (with 2.7.0 client library) in local environment ( with kafka version 2.6.0) and it worked fine but wanted to get the supported compatibility between them

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As **onecricketeer** has helpfully pointed out, you can refer to the [Kafka Compatability Matrix](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix).  He also notes:

> There is a general answer. Clients above 0.10.2 work with brokers down to that version for all basic functionality until stated otherwise. Extra functionality includes transactional/idempotence and record headers, which Spring may depend on, but Kafka Streams natively has no dependency on.

Additionally, the [upgrade section of the Kafka Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade) provides guidance on upgrade order for various Kafka versions.

The compatability matrix provided by the [spring-cloud-stream](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/Kafka-Client-Compatibility) project may also be of assistance.

Comment: There is a general answer. Clients above 0.10.2 work with brokers down to that version for all basic functionality until stated otherwise. Extra functionality includes transactional/idempotence and record headers, which Spring may depend on, but Kafka Streams natively has no dependency on

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a source/link that documents this?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

Comment: @OneCricketeer The link is old one and it has not been updated for kafka 2.7

Comment: @Sunil Doesn't need to be updated, IMO. Anything beyond 1.0  is the same for purposes of the clients. 2.0 really only was a Java8/Scala2.12 change. You can also see it says on the broker _since 2.2.1 and 2.3.0 message format 0.11+ is required_, but if you're using client versions lower than this without record headers, for example, the broker knows how to up-convert the messages

Answer (score 0):

Just found more reliable and up-to-date source:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/faq.html#which-versions-of-ak-clusters-are-supported-by-kstreams